# How to creat a button programmatically with JavaFX?

Tags: button, javafx

I want to make a button on an AnchorPane without drag it from the library in the FXML file I want to do it progammatically: if the search button clicked, should show a new button not existed in the AnchorPane before I did this code but I don't know what is wrong with it:

```
private void searchButton(ActionEvent evt)  {

    Button tab = new Button();
    tab.setLayoutX(147);
    tab.setLayoutY(102);
    tab.setText("Tab1");
    tab.setPrefHeight(27);
    tab.setPrefWidth(69);
    WebView wb = new WebView();
    wb.setLayoutX(-1);
    wb.setLayoutY(128);
    wb.setPrefWidth(1604);
    wb.setPrefWidth(700);
}
```

Comment: You never add the `Button` to anything in the scene graph.

Comment: ok so can you show me how please ?

Comment: Not without more information. Where do you want the button to appear?

Comment: i want it to appear on the AnchorPane in the FXML file

Comment: So please show the code from the FXML file where the anchor pane is defined, and the code in the controller where it is injected.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you searchButton method is in controller attached to some FXML. Then all you need to do is this:

```
yourAnchorPane.getChildren().add(tab);
```

If you don't have already published reference to anchorPane in your controller, then add this into your controller

```
@FXML
AnchorPane yourAnchorPane;
```

And in SceneBuilder select your anchorPane, go to code tab and enter "yourAnchorPane" as fx:id.

Further info on working with anchorpane is [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html).

---

You probably also want to set some constraints on the tab to locate it at a position within the AnchorPane.  For instance, the following code will locate your button `tab` relative to the top left corner of the AnchorPane: Ten pixels down and fifteen pixels to the right.

```
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tab, 10.0); 
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tab, 15.0);
```